# I want to create Android application for Camera with chroma video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I want to create an Android application which can shoot video and merge with overlay video which will be having chroma key.

**Concept :-** Video recording with having overlay video and audio.

I tried to use Surface View/ Texture View and FFMPEG. In which Surface View/ Texture View are failures.
FFMPEG is working but there are plenty of drawbacks like,

1. Processing time is very high.
2. Zoom/ PAN features are not satisfying.
3. Zoom in feature us absent.

Can you please suggest something, I know plenty of application doing same but no idea how.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: maybe [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) will help you achieve what you want

Comment: There are plenty of examples of modifying the camera frames while recording. The cleanest one, probably, is the official [HDR example](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/HdrViewfinder), using SurfaceView.